# Non-US polynomial division notation

Tags: polynomials

I am looking for examples of how polynomial division is presented to secondary students outside of the US. Wikipedia has a nice presentation of this for integer division [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Notation_in_non-English-speaking_countries). Do you know of anything similar for polynomial division?

Comment: See [mathematics.se]; better to inquire there about notation used in mathematics, as used in the US or otherwise. This site is by and for mathematics educators, as its title indicates, and concerns mathematics education. If your question concerns mathematics education, and how to teach polynomial division in some other country, please edit your post to add such context.

Comment: Thanks. This is for a curriculum writing project and I'm interested in answers to the question I asked.

Comment: @Jason - are you suggesting the [polynomial long division example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example) isn't the same for non-US math instruction?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer It is the same in principle, but the look of it may be slightly different. Basically, take the example from Wikipedia for a single number and replace it with a polynomial.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes, I expect the approaches to polynomial division to have a similar bookkeeping difference to what is done in the US as the approaches to polynomial division do, but I'd like some documentation of that. I did find this [book](http://sitios.educando.edu.do/biblioteca/components/com_booklibrary/ebooks/algebrabaldorc.pdf) that seems to be popular in latin america. (See page 95 for an example of polynomial division.)

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to why this is a question about mathematics and not education.  The OP says "is presented to secondary students" and so presumably relevant?

Comment: I've deleted many duplicate comments here that are making the same point -- that some users believe the question belongs on math.SE instead. After one or two comments of this type, the discussion devolved a bit. Anyone else who thinks this question is off-topic should feel free to vote to close the question, or post a meta question if more discussion is desired.

Comment: A similar question related specifically to Norway: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/16557/what-is-the-notation-for-polynomial-long-division-in-norway

Comment: In India, the schools that come under the Central Board of Secondary Education (CBSE) use the same notation as in the Wikipedia article for polynomial long division. [Here](http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/jemh102.pdf) is an official PDF of the relevant chapter on polynomials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a Russian 7th grade algebra textbook ([publisher's website](https://catalog.prosv.ru/item/4872)). Attached is a complete section dedicated to polynomial division, it is marked as optional.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. And also thanks for your comment above about the approach in Norway.

Answer (score 9):

In Italy, polynomial long division is usually presented as in the following example taken from one of the most widely used textbooks for first year high school students (M. Bergamini, G. Barozzi, A. Trifone, *Matematica.blu 1*, Zanichelli):

[image: Polynomial long division]

Answer (score 9):

In Greece the students are taught polynomial division in the second class of upper high school (grade 11 at US educational system). It is the same algorithm as in Italy and Russia. Whole book in pdf form is available [here.](http://ebooks.edu.gr/modules/document/document.php?course=DSGL-B133&download=/4e09fabdb67e/4e09fac5l2ig)

[image: Polynomial division in Greece secondary education]